# How do you make a bot DM the mentioned role with the message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

And before I changed the args it just DMed the users with the role @deleted-role
This is my code and the error is under it

```
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}dm`)) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
        if (!args[0]) return message.reply('you need to provide a role')
if (!args[1]) return message.reply('you need to provide a message')
const role = message.mentions.roles.first()
message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.id).members.forEach(member => member.send(args[1]))
    }
})

------------------------------------------

message.guild.roles.cache.get(role.id).members.forEach(member => member.send(args[1]))
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: `role` returns undefined

Comment: Wdym role returns undefined?

Comment: Of undefined means the parent element is returnung undefined, therefor `role` is undefined